# What happened to the Predator blaster at the end of AVP Requiem

Tags: aliens-vs-predator-requiem

During a battle between the Predator and the Aliens the Predator's shoulder cannons are damaged. As a result he modifies one into a hand-held blaster. In the final battle Dallas ends up with the blaster before it is taken off him by the special forces when the helicopter crashes.

The Predator's blaster cannon is presented by Colonel Stevens to a Ms. Yutani in what i think is the last scene of the film. I think she says something about earth/humans not being ready for this technology yet.

So what happens to the blaster after this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think we can make a reasonable assumption that the Yutani Corp uses this technology to kickstart their own scientific breakthroughs. This would explain why they are bedfellows with Weyland in the future stories. The actual artifact itself would be disassembled for analysis.

I see this as the equivalent of Cyberdine systems getting their hands on the original arm and chip from *The Terminator*, thus setting their own wheels in motion.

Comment: I think this answer is correct. 

"The Reverse-Engineering division was developed after such incidents as the destruction of Gunnison County and the buy-out of Borgia Industries. Weyland-Yutani would capture alien tech and attempt to reverse engineer it. They would steal tech such as Predator weapons and Space Jockey technology. However, they would run afoul of the Predators, who were fiercely protective of their technology."

That was taken from here. http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Weyland-Yutani

Answer (score 0):

The ceremonial spear given to Lex at the end of the AvP movie will end up in the upcoming The Predator movie (released in 2018) along with the City Hunters spear from Predator 2. There is a small chance that this cannon might be at least referenced in the new movie.

Check more here:
https://geektyrant.com/news/new-photos-from-the-predator-and-details-on-reshoots-reveal-references-to-other-predator-films